# Hockey minigame scoreboard doesn’t work

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I run a small server that focuses on towny but also has a couple minigames on top of that. I added hockey rink that uses knockback 10 sticks and a pig with a bunch of health to play the game with. I have a button that gives a countdown and then spawns the pig.

But can I make it so that when the pig enters the goal area, it turns on a lamp, then kills the pig? Then someone can press the spawn button and when they score a second goal, a second lamp illuminates, there will also be a set of lamps for each team. Then, when the game is over, someone presses a button, and the lamps all turn off and the game resets.

So far since I don't know any command block stuff, I tried using some redstone, hoppers, pistons, dispensers and other stuff to try to build one without command blocks, but it doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 1):

OK so look at this picture I will tell you what to put in each block

[image]

first put a command block at the end of the summoning that says `/setbock <X of redstone (X) in picture> <Y of redstone (X) in picture> <Z of redstone (X) in picture> minecraft:redstone_block` put the X Y and Z somewhere no one will see this will be the redstone block (X) in the picture

for 1 have a repeating command block that is needs redstone says
`/kill @e[type=Pig,x=<X of one corner>
y=<Y of one corner>,z=<Z of one corner>,dx=<distance on X from one corner to the other>,
dy=<distance on Y from one corner to the other>,
dz=<distance on Z from one corner to the other>`
replace all  with the actual distance of the X/Y/Z

for 2 have a chain command block off of that that is always active and conditional that says
`/setblock <X of behind 1st Lamp> <Y of behind 1st Lamp> <Z of behind 1st Lamp> minecraft:redstone_block`
once again replace all  with the actual X/Y/Z

Have command block 3 be chain always active and conditional and have this command`/setbock <X of wool> <Y of wool> <Z of wool> minecraft:redstone_block`

now in command block 4 make it put this command `/setbock <X of redstone (X) in picture> 
<Y of redstone (X) in picture> <Z of redstone (X) in picture> minecraft:redstone_block` Now set the X Y and Z to whare you put the redstone block earlier

5 is the same as one

6 is conditional always active and chain`/setblock <X of behind 2nd Lamp> <Y of behind 2nd Lamp> <Z of behind 2nd Lamp> minecraft:redstone_block`

now you need a reset button make it go into a impulse needs redstone unconditional and make it say `/setbock <X of wool> <Y of wool> <Z of wool> minecraft:air`

Now copy this for the other goal

now you should be done hopefuly this works by the way what is your server's IP?

Comment: Oh wow thanks so much! My server is just a small one but the website is www.SurvivalTown.Enjin.com

Answer (score -1):

You could do this with Command Blocks, checking if theres nearby entities that are a pig, then if there is it triggers another command block that powers a lamp then have a delay to destroy the lamp.

Comment: Telling people to go elsewhere for an answer is the opposite of being helpful.  Rather, flesh out your answer to provide additional details on how to make this work.